# How to combine two rules into one?

Tags: jess

I wanted to know how to combine two of my rules, for example:

```
(defrule Rules::pants
  (declare (auto-focus TRUE))
(answer (ident color) (text red))
  (answer (ident pants) (text yes))
  =>
(printout t "you are wearing red pants"))

(defrule Rules::shirt
  (declare (auto-focus TRUE))
(answer (ident shirt) (text blue))
  (answer (ident red) (text yes))
  =>
(printout t "you are wearing blue shirt"))
```

If I would write these two rules like:

```
(defrule Rules::pants
  (declare (auto-focus TRUE))
(answer (ident red) (text yes))
  (answer (ident pants) (text yes))
(answer (ident shirt) (text yes))
  (answer (ident blue) (text yes))
  =>
(printout t "you are wearing blue shirt and red pants"))
```

I want it to act like an `OR` statement, to be triggered if any of the conditions is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive answer would be

```
(defrule Rules::pants      
  (or (and (answer (ident red) (text yes))
           (answer (ident pants) (text yes)))
      (and (answer (ident shirt) (text yes))
           (answer (ident blue) (text yes)))
  )
 =>
   (printout t "you are wearing blue shirt or red pants")
)
```

The first snag is that this rule fires twice if the the person has red pants *and* a blue shirt. Most likely, this doesn't matter because the person isn't identified, so we may assume that only one person is on the catwalk.

**Edited** The second snag would happen if properties aren't associated with each other, i.e., when a colour and an item can be combined freely. Consider a redneck with blue denim pants and a red checkered shirt. The rule would fire because there is "pants" and "shirts" and "red" and "blue", sufficient to match according to the pattern. But OP has asserted in a comment (see below) that there is some way to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks I guess that works, I just didn't get what the problem could be, could you please explain a little bit more if possible?

Comment: Just insert (answer shirt yes), (answer red yes), (answer pants yes), (answer blue yes) for a gent wearing a red shirt and blue pants.

Comment: oh no, I will add some other information to make it mean something, this was just the part i was having problems with, Thanks